# How can I input value in TextBox with Selenium VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I have this part of HTML:

```
<input id="naklName" type="text" placeholder="input number document" class="form-control" align="left">
```

and I can't input value in TextBox with Selenium VBA.
May be it works without Selenium.

I tried first XPATH:

```
bot.FindElementByXpath("//*[@id='naklName']").SendKeys "123"
```

and other combinations with CLASS, Css, ID. But always `NotFoundElement`.
My VBA code like as:

```
 Dim bot As New WebDriver   
    bot.Start "chrome", "url"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the HTML:

[image: html]

To send a *character sequence* within the `<input>` you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *FindElementByCss*:

  ```
  bot.FindElementByCss("label[for='naklName']").SendKeys "ENOT"
  ```
- Using *FindElementByXPath*:

  ```
  bot.FindElementByXPath("//label[@for='naklName']").SendKeys "ENOT"
  ```

Comment: yeah, I know, but i cant now. Need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote.